# Rails 3: Issue with merging scopes

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Database: MySQL

Following are scopes added,

```
default_scope where("current = ? AND archived_at IS NULL", true)

scope :expirables,
  -> { where("expiry_date IS NOT NULL") }
scope :ready_to_expire,
  -> { expirables.where(expiry_date: (1.months.ago..Date.today)) }
scope :expired,
  -> { expirables.where("DATE(expiry_date) < ?", Date.today) }
```

The result queries are generated as follows,

#### Document.expirables

`SELECT documents.* FROM documents  WHERE (documents.current = 1 AND documents.archived_at IS NULL) AND (expiry_date IS NOT NULL)`

#### Document.ready_to_expire

`SELECT documents.* FROM documents  WHERE documents.`expiry_date`BETWEEN '2015-06-08 13:03:40' AND '2015-07-08' AND (current = 1 AND archived_at IS NULL) AND (expiry_date IS NOT NULL)`

#### Document.expired

`SELECT documents.* FROM documents  WHERE (current = 1 AND archived_at IS NULL) AND (expiry_date IS NOT NULL) AND (DATE(expiry_date) < '2015-07-08')`

Note the place of `(expiry_date IS NOT NULL)` in both 2nd and 3rd query strings. I'm expecting this to append before the other conditions. But it generates query different in both the cases.

Notice `(current = 1 AND archived_at IS NULL)`, this condition is a `default_scope` in the model.

I'm confused why the `expirables` scope attached first in once case and last in another case. And it also creates problem where it checks date ranges irrespective to the they are `NULL` or not.

Is there any workaround to fix this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Venkat I would strongly recommend that you eliminate the `default_scope`.  It will lead to headaches down the road.  If you cannot do so, to circumvent you can use `Documents.unscoped....`.  On your Q, you should chain scopes in calls, not the scopes themselves.  So, define them independently and then call such as `Documents.expirables.expired`.

Comment: Thanks @steveklein. But chaining in calls also results the same.

Comment: I would think this was due to `default_scope` but removing default scope also does not help. The problem is same.

Answer (score 0):

I would be very surprised if the mysql query optimization engine cared about the order of the conditional clauses; did you `explain` it both ways and see?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html

Mysql is limited in how it can optimize `is null` conditions, so your queries checking both `expiry_date` and `archived_at` probably won't both be optimized:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/is-null-optimization.html